# Why is the IF statement not working here?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm doing this beginner mini project. the if statement isn't working

the if statement

```
const value = document.getElementById("value")
const btnDecrease = document.querySelector(".decrease")
const btnReset = document.querySelector(".reset")
const btnIncrease = document.querySelector(".increase")

let count = 0

btnDecrease.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count--
    value.textContent = count
   
})

btnIncrease.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count++
    value.textContent = count
   
})

btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count = 0
    value.textContent = count
})


if (count > 0) {
    value.style.color = "Green";
} else if (count < 0) {
    value.style.color = "red";
} else {
    value.style.color = "#222"
}
```

should turn the count red if it's a negative value, and green if it's positive

Comment: The `if` statement isn't connected in any way to changes to `count`. The event handlers should call a function that updates the color based on `count`. *(Discussion regarding encapsulation and global vars deferred.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your `if` statements are only running **once**, before any values are entered.

Extract it into a function instead and call it after the count is changed each time.

```js
function update() {
    if (count > 0) {
        value.style.color = "Green";
    } else if (count < 0) {
        value.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        value.style.color = "#222"
    }
    value.textContent = count;
}
btnDecrease.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count--;
    update();
});
btnIncrease.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count++
    update();
});
btnReset.addEventListener("click", function() {
    count = 0;
    update();
});
```